# How to import a file into Spyder

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

To learn python, I'm attempting the infamous [baby names exercise](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/exercises/baby-names).

I'm having trouble getting going. How do I import the file `babynames.py` from the folder `C:\Users\user1\Desktop\google-python-exercises\babynames`?

The directory is set to `cd C:\Users\user1\Desktop\google-python-exercises\babynames`, but the commmand `import babynames` is invalid.

I searched around for an answer, but most of the Google results I've found solve much more complex variations of this simple example.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be importing the file - the instructions want you to edit the `babynames.py` directly. What you'll need to do is (assuming you're using spyder due to the tag on your question):

1. find and open `babynames.py` from Spyder
2. read through the file, follow the instructions, and edit where it is marked with `your code here`
3. run the file to test it. If you need to enter args (eg. for the default babynames code you need to give the output file with `--summaryfile <file>.html`, write them in the `Command line options` box in the run configuration dialog in Spyder.

If you're using the command prompt instead, you will need to edit the file using any text editor, and to run it, enter a command like: `python babynames.py --summaryfile some-file.txt` where the working directory is `C:\Users\user1\Desktop\google-python-exercises\babynames` and `python` is on your path. (you may need to give a different command to run python itself from cmd - it will depend on your setup).